# Resolve conflict in git

Tags: git

I have own a repository whose structure currently is shown below

[image]

As you can see at some point there's a divergence. The master branch has a CMake file that builds a visual studio solution and it is missing a couple of files that have been implemented in the FibonacciHeap-Implementation branch, however before implementing the CMake file the project started as a visual studio project (there was no CMake file back then, also the folder structure was a bit different). Later I made some changes in two sources in the FibonacciHeap-Branch and now I'd like to merge/push those changes in master, but I'm getting conflicts.

**Attempts**

I did try a `git merge master` from the fibonacci heap repository, but I get deleted the files I'm interested to keep, so I did `git reset --hard`.

If I do:

`git pull origin master --rebase` I get the error:

```
From https://github.com/lukkio88/CPP-AlgAndDS
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Changed struct Node with class Node
Applying: fibonacciHeap implementation draft
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
A   BasicAlgorithmsAndDataStructures/AdvancedDataStructures/AdvancedDataStructures.vcxproj
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
CONFLICT (modify/delete): BasicAlgorithmsAndDataStructures/AdvancedDataStructures/AdvancedDataStructures.vcxproj deleted in a3e2c216e74a90fdfbcae805b2caf2a54a7edb4a and modified in fibonacciHeap implementation draft. Version fibonacciHeap implementation draft of BasicAlgorithmsAndDataStructures/AdvancedDataStructures/AdvancedDataStructures.vcxproj left in tree.
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 fibonacciHeap implementation draft
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

What can I do?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you choose to `merge` or `rebase` - you have real conflicts between the branches, and you have to solve them.

Comment: Another option is to `git checkout FibonacciHeap-Implementation` and `git rebase master`, followed by `git checkout master` and `git merge FibonacciHeap-Implementation`. The rebase will show the same conflicts, though, and you'll have to resolve them manually anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to merge the branch `FibonacciHeap-Implementation` into `master`, you should do the opposite :

```
# First, checkout master branch
> git checkout master
# Then merge the branch into it
> git merge FibonacciHeap-Implementation
```

If you have conflicts, you can resolve them either manually (locate the `>>>>`, `=====`, `<<<<<<` sections and keep the one you want, or use an external mergetool.

To use an external merge tool, you need to configure it first. For example, to configure vimdiff :

```
git config merge.tool vimdiff
```

And then to start the tool from CLI when you have a conflict :

```
git mergetool
```

There are many tools depending on your platform and preferences, have a look there : https://gist.github.com/karenyyng/f19ff75c60f18b4b8149 for further understanding of mergetools.